# How to fix syntax for fuzzing network layer on Sulley fuzzer

Tags: syntax, fuzzer

I was following the codes from https://www.slideshare.net/htbridge/fuzzing-an-introduction-to-sulley-framework.

Below is the codes for kickfuzz.py. I faced invalid syntax for kickfuzz.py

```
from sulley import *
from requests import httpcallAX

sess=sessions.session(session_filename="audits/http.session")
target = sessions.target("192.168.175.129", 30888)
target.netmon = pedrpc.client("192.168.175.129", 26001)
target.procmon = pedrpc.client("192.168.175.129", 26002)
@ target.procmon_options = ( "proc_name" | "tvMobiliService.exe" )

target.procmon_options = \
(
"proc_name"        : "tvMobiliService.exe",
"stop_commands"    : ['net stop tvMobiliService'],
"start_commands"   : ['net start tvMobiliService'],
)

sess.add_target(target)
sess.connect(sess.root, s_get("HTTP"))
sess.fuzz()
```

File "C:/sulley_build/sulley/kickfuzz.py", line 8
    @ target.procmon_options = ("proc_name" | "tvMobiliService.exe")
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, the correct code should be below. If you are following the same example from the link, httpcallAX.py should be placed in /sulley/requests folder.

```
from sulley import *
from requests import httpcallAX

sess=sessions.session(session_filename="audits/http.session")
target = sessions.target("192.168.175.129", 30888)
target.netmon = pedrpc.client("192.168.175.129", 26001)
target.procmon = pedrpc.client("192.168.175.129", 26002)
# target.procmon_options = {"proc_name" : "tvMobiliService.exe"}

target.procmon_options = \
    {
    "proc_name"        : "tvMobiliService.exe",
    "stop_commands"    : ['net stop tvMobiliService'],
    "start_commands"   : ['net start tvMobiliService'],
    }

sess.add_target(target)
sess.connect(sess.root, s_get("HTTP"))
sess.fuzz()
```